# .NET Core 6 Web API - Migrate to Lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, aws-lambda

I recently reverted my .NET Core 7 Web Api to .NET Core 6 Web API which is working fine locally; however, after adding AWS configurations (below) and deploying this as a fully fledged API, I follow the Lambda function url I created and I receive a blank page which states `Internal Server Error`. I figured there may be issues related to folder naming structure (since they changed throughout the development process) when attempting to use the `.NET Lambda CLI` but I have not been able to get it to work directly through the Visual Studio 2022 toolkit either. I tested the default `WeatherForecast` controller based API and was successful in getting it to run. How can I get this application to work without fully refactoring the app?

**Added the following package:**

`<PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.Hosting" Version="1.6.0" />`

**Added to csproj as the last item in the PropertyGroup:**

`<AWSProjectType>Lambda</AWSProjectType>`

**Tried adding:**

`builder.Services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.RestApi);`

**then:**

`builder.Services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.HttpApi);`

The HttpApi service worked for the WeatherForecast controller api so I had hoped it would in this project as well.

My original folder structure:

ProjectName

- ProjectName.Api

with a ProjectName.csproj

Recent attempt

ProjectName-Backend

- ProjectName

with ProjectName.csproj

I have tried renaming the project folder to be the same as the original solution folder. I haven't tried naming both the parent folder and project folder to match the solution name, might this work or is my problem deeper?

Additionally, whenever testing the function url via AWS I am getting a message that the project aborted. Will test again and add in an error code later.

Thank you so much.

`Edit:`

I moved my project into the solution folder and renamed everything ProjectNameApi, so

ProjectNameApi

- ProjectNameApi.csproj

`Function name:`
ProjectNameTestApi

`Function Handler`
ProjectNameApi

Still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

While restructuring my project may have helped, I believe the issue was that my original api was serving static files:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Images")),
    RequestPath = "/images"
});
```

By removing this line and the associated functionality I was able to get the Lambda function working appropriately.